# How can I make my long methods shorter in Java?

Tags: java, methods

I am beginner in Java and my problem is that my methods often gets very long. I have been told that methods should be as short as possible and one method should only be doing one thing. For example I have made a program where you can auction on dogs. I need tips on how I can break out smaller methods out of this long one but still get it to work the same way. Here is my code:

```
private void makeNewBid() {

System.out.println("Enter the name of the user>");
String userName = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
User u = getUser(userName);
if (userName == null || !userRegister.contains(u)) {
    System.out.println("error. no such user");
    return;


}else {


Auction bidAuction = null;
String name = dogLowerCaseTrim();
Dog d = getDog(name);
for(Auction a: auctionRegister ) {
    if(auctionRegister.equals(name.toLowerCase())) {
        bidAuction = a;
        break;
    }
}
Auction a = getAuctionedDog(d);
if(bidAuction != null) {
    System.out.println("error. this dog is not up for auction.");

    return;
}

System.out.print("Amount to bid: min " + (getAuctionedDog(d).getTopBid()+ 1 )+ "> ");
int amount = input.nextInt();   
while(amount <= a.getTopBid()) {
    System.out.println("error. too low bid");
    System.out.println("Amount to bid: min " + (getAuctionedDog(d).getTopBid() + 1));
    amount = input.nextInt();


}
Bid b = new Bid(u, amount);
getAuctionedDog(d).addBid(b);
System.out.println("Bid made");
input.nextLine();

}    

}
```

Comment: *First* make them *readable* by letting your IDE format your code. Then come back and [edit] your question with the readable code. While you are at it, describe in words what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Also, I'd like to know what "shorter" means in this context.  What in particular was pointed out that might not be "one thing" and that you might want to factor out of this method?  This question might be better suited to the SO's sister site Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

Your method violates the [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), which is part of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) design principles.

From "Clean Code"

Size

> The first rule of functions is that they should be small. The second
>   rule of functions is that they should be smaller than that.

Blocks and Indenting

> [...] functions should not be large enough to hold nested structures.

Do one thing

> FUNCTIONS SHOULD DO ONE THING. THEY SHOULD DO IT WELL. THEY SHOULD DO
>   IT ONLY.

The book goes further with more things to keep your functions clean, but I think just implementing those in your example is already some work.

- Create a method to get the user.
- Create a method to get the big    auction.
- Create a method to get the amount.

Preferably, create a service to hold all these methods.

Do not stop your method flow like that, instead create your exception and throw that exception.

```
System.out.println("error. no such user");
return;
```

Do not name your variables like that. Instead use meaningful variable names, that will increase your code's readability both for your future self, but also for other people.

```
Dog d = getDog(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the question "I have been told that methods should be as short as possible and one method should only be doing one thing."
This is actually two different statements:

1. methods should be as short as possible
2. method should only be doing one thing.

For the first statement:

In general I would reject the first statement. The shortest way to write a method tends to be some unreadable garbage of obfuscated code.
However making the code easier to understand will often result in lesser lines of code. Also if you follow your second statement you will end up with lesser lines. 
So while I think trying to create the least lines of code is not beneficial at all, a lot of lines give indication to review a code if it can be improved(But review itself shouldn't focus on the lines of code. It should focus on the quality of the code).

For the second statement:

This statement holds true! A method should concentrate on one task and do that right. It should have as little sideeffects as possible.

You call it to do something. If it does something additional you very likely to run into a problem sooner or later when you call it for the original purpose. Or the other way round you can't call it in a different situation as it does things you don't want to be done.

Also for clarity a method that has a clear purpose is easy to understand and check: does it do what it should? Or does it do something wrong? You can easily create a test that checks the method if you want to be sure.

Now for you code:
First off as an excuse, your example "as is" is not realy ideal to show how to approach. Also parts are missing that may or may not give room for further improvements. So don't be to dogmatic but rather concentrate on the underlying idea to break up your code into some logical units(as you requested).

a) You have some user identification:

```
System.out.println("Enter the name of the user>");
String userName = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
User u = getUser(userName);
if (userName == null || !userRegister.contains(u)) {
    System.out.println("error. no such user");
    return;

}
```

That identification seems to be a logical unit that can be put in its own method. It identifies a user.

b) You fetch some bidAuction from a container defined somewhere else:

```
for(Auction a: auctionRegister ) {
    if(auctionRegister.equals(name.toLowerCase())) {
        bidAuction = a;
        break;
    }
}
```

That peace could be a separate method that fetches an item by its name: "getBidAuction(String name)".

c) Next you have a bid:

```
System.out.print("Amount to bid: min " + (getAuctionedDog(d).getTopBid()+ 1 )+ "> ");
int amount = input.nextInt();   
while(amount <= a.getTopBid()) {
    System.out.println("error. too low bid");
    System.out.println("Amount to bid: min " + (getAuctionedDog(d).getTopBid() + 1));
    amount = input.nextInt();
}
Bid b = new Bid(u, amount);
```

That again resembles a code that could be put in a method that would return the bid: "Bid getBid(User user, Auction auction){".

**With that you would end up with this - which is still not optimal(some hints on the logic and on what other methods are doing is missing)  but broken up a little** :

```
public class NewClass {

    User identifyUser() {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the user>");
        String userName = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        User user = getUser(userName);
        if (userName == null || !userRegister.contains(user)) {
            System.out.println("error. no such user");
            return null;
        }
        return user;
    }

    Auction findAuction(String name) {
        Auction bidAuction = null;
        for (Auction a : auctionRegister) {
            if (auctionRegister.equals(name.toLowerCase())) {
                return a;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    Bid getBid(User user, Auction auction) {
        System.out.print("Amount to bid: min " + (auction.getTopBid() + 1) + "> ");
        int amount = input.nextInt();
        while (amount <= auction.getTopBid()) {
            System.out.println("error. too low bid");
            System.out.println("Amount to bid: min " + (auction.getTopBid() + 1));
            amount = input.nextInt();

        }
        return new Bid(user, amount);
    }

    void makeNewBid() {
        User user = identifyUser();
        if (null == user) {
            return; //use an exception instead.
        }
        String name = dogLowerCaseTrim();
        Auction bidAuction = findAuction(name);
        //is this realy what you intended?!
        if (bidAuction != null) {
            System.out.println("error. this dog is not up for auction.");
            return; //use an exception instead?
        }
        Dog dog = getDog(name);
        //might this be the same as bidAuction?!
        Auction auction = getAuctionedDog(dog);
        Bid bid = getBid(user, auction);
        auction.addBid(bid);
        System.out.println("Bid made");
        input.nextLine();

    }
}
```

Next question that arises is why does a user register for every bid again? Shouldn't that be done somewhere else? Can it even happen that a not registered user places a bid? Most likely it should be checked outside the method.

Same may be the case for the "auction" item. Depends.

What does getAuctionedDog() do? Is it superfluent? Does it resemble the findAuction? So is "bidAuction" the same object as "auction"? -- can't say from the code. If not: maybe it should! If so: use the one you have and remove the second(And with it the in this case superfluent dog object).

Is the comparison "if (bidAuction != null) {" logically what you want? - I can't say from your code but very likely you want it the other way round "if (bidAuction == null) {" .

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! Actually that is not user registration, I've  already got a method where the user is registered and stored in an arraylist. The user need to exist in that arraylist to make a bid. getAuctionDog() checks if a dog is up for auction because the program can store dogs in a register before you put them up for auction. Ok, so when I have done new methods as you recommended, how do i get it to run in the same way? Do I make a new method where I call on these methods in the correct order?

Comment: for the user "registration":  You may give it a better name then ;) That part does not only check but also asks the user to enter a name.  So it is kind of a "login" so maybe call it like that or "identifyUser" or "authenticateUser" ...

Comment: Yes you are right, that sounds better! Thank you a lot for the help I really appreciate it! :)